# python pandas json_normalize in 1.0.0 with meta path specified - expects iterable

Tags: python, json, pandas, normalize

I have the data

```
[{"state": "Florida",
         "shortname": "FL",
         "info": {"governor": "Rick Scott"},
         "counties": [{"name": "Dade",
                       "population": 12345,
                       "Attributes": [
                         {
                          "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                          "Spirit_code": "TRLQR",
                          "value": 1
                         },
                         {
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "HAVPN",
                            "value": 57000
                        }

                       ]},
                       {"name": "Broward",
                        "population": 40000,
                         "Attributes": [
                         {
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "GMSTP",
                            "value": 14
                        },
                        {
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "GWTPN",
                            "value": 11212
                        }
                       ]
                       },
                       {"name": "Palm Beach",
                        "population": 60000,
                        "Attributes": [{
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "YGHMN",
                            "value": 154.01
                        },
                        {
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "CXZASD",
                            "value": 154.01
                        }]
                       }
         ]},
        {"state": "Ohio",
         "shortname": "OH",
         "info": {"governor": "John Kasich"},
         "counties": [{"name": "Summit", "population": 1234,
                      "Attributes": [{
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "QWERTY",
                            "value": 154.01
                        },
                        {
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "JKLGH",
                            "value": 154.01
                        }]
         },
                      {"name": "Cuyahoga", "population": 1337,
                      "Attributes": [{
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "ASDF",
                            "value": 154.01
                        },
                        {
                            "capture_date": "2020-01-29",
                            "Spirit_code": "POIUY",
                            "value": 154.01
                        }]

                      }],
        }
]
```

And I am looking for the result:

```
state,   shortname, name,       population, attirbute.capture_date, attirbute.spirit_code, attirbute.value
florida, FL        ,Dade,       12345     , 2020-0-29             , TRLQR                , 1
florida, FL        ,Dade,       12345     , 2020-0-29             , HAVPN                , 57000
florida, FL        ,Broward,    40000     , 2020-0-29             , GMSTP                , 14
florida, FL        ,Broward,    40000     , 2020-0-29             , GWTPN                , 11212
florida, FL        ,Palm Beach, 60000     , 2020-0-29             , YGHMN                , 154.01
florida, FL        ,Palm Beach, 60000     , 2020-0-29             , YGHMN                , 154.01
florida, FL        ,Palm Beach, 60000     , 2020-0-29             , CXZASD                , 154.01
```

Basically normalizing for the key attributes in the nested json. Key: "Attributes".

```
json_normalize(data["data"], ["counties", "Attributes"], ["state", "shortname", ["counties", "name"], ["counties", "population"]])
```

I am getting error:

```
TypeError: {'name': 'Dade', 'population': 12345, 'Attributes': [{'capture_date': '2020-01-29', 'Spirit_code': 'TRLQR', 'value': 1}, {'capture_date': '2020-01-29', 'Spirit_code': 'HAVPN', 'value': 57000}]} has non iterable value 12345 for path ['population']. Must be iterable or null.
```

but if I run :

```
plots_in = json_normalize(data["data"], ["counties", "Attributes"],
                   ["state", "shortname", ["counties", "name"]])
```

I get the result:

```
  capture_date Spirit_code     value    state shortname counties.name
0   2020-01-29       TRLQR      1.00  Florida        FL          Dade
1   2020-01-29       HAVPN  57000.00  Florida        FL          Dade
2   2020-01-29       GMSTP     14.00  Florida        FL       Broward
3   2020-01-29       GWTPN  11212.00  Florida        FL       Broward
4   2020-01-29       YGHMN    154.01  Florida        FL    Palm Beach
5   2020-01-29      CXZASD    154.01  Florida        FL    Palm Beach
6   2020-01-29      QWERTY    154.01     Ohio        OH        Summit
7   2020-01-29       JKLGH    154.01     Ohio        OH        Summit
8   2020-01-29        ASDF    154.01     Ohio        OH      Cuyahoga
9   2020-01-29       POIUY    154.01     Ohio        OH      Cuyahoga
```

is there something to do with the integer value in the population key?
because if I run the following then still I am getting the same error:

```
plots_in = json_normalize(data["data"], ["counties", "population"])
```

Please explain, if someone knows what is going on underneath?

Comment: Does anyone know, what exactly is going on beneath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your version of pandas. If it pandas 1.0.0 then it is most likely related to:
[json_normalize in 1.0.0 with meta path specified - expects iterable #31507](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31507)

I had exactly the same issue as I reinstalled my dev environment in linux including installation of all latest packages with pandas 1.0.0. After some search I found the above link and then removed the pandas 1.0.0 and installed pandas 0.25.3 by first uninstalling:

```
pip3 uninstall pandas # or pip uninstall pandas
```

and then:

```
pip3 install pandas==0.25.3 # or pip install pandas==0.25.3
```

and after that everything worked fine as it did before installing latest pandas.

Comment: Glad that it was helpful.

Comment: is there any way, we can achieve the same result using pyspark?

Comment: You might want to to post this as another question, I am new in spark.

Comment: The issue was solved already. You can use Pandas 1.0.5

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
# s is the given json sample
df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(s)

# unnest the list
df['counties'] = df['counties'].str[0]

# convert counties dict into cols
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('counties').apply(pd.Series)],  axis=1)

# unnest the list
df['Attributes'] = df['Attributes'].str[0]

# convert Attributes dict into cols
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop('Attributes').apply(pd.Series)],  axis=1)

print(df)

     state shortname info.governor    name  population capture_date  \
0  Florida        FL    Rick Scott    Dade       12345   2020-01-29   
1     Ohio        OH   John Kasich  Summit        1234   2020-01-29   

  Spirit_code   value  
0       TRLQR    1.00  
1      QWERTY  154.01
```